# Trying to figure out what says here and what this artifact is

Tags: translation, meaning

I'm not sure if this language is Chinese or Japanese, pardon my ignorance, but I'm trying to figure out what it says here and what this artifact is.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be the end piece of a folding fan. Maybe the rest of the fan is missing?

The characters should be read from right to left:
金澤 jin1ze2
櫻谷特製 ying1gu3 te4zhi4

金澤 is the Japanese city Kanazawa. 櫻谷 means "Cherry blossom gorge" and would be pronounced "Sakuraya" in Japanese. This is probably the name of a place or a company. 特製 means "special product of".

So presumably this is a special product of Sakuraya in Kanazawa. While the names appear to be Japanese, these words would mean exactly the same thing in Chinese.

Comment: Thank you very much @KWeiss for your help! I can't upvote your answer for my low reputation in this community but your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: @Jean Paul Ruiz you can accept this answer by clicking the check mark below the up /down arrows

Comment: Done, thanks again @KWeiss. On an update, we went deeper and found out that this is actually a Tessen, or at least a reproduction of a Tessen, a Japanese war fan is a fan designed for use in warfare, well, it was apparently designed to look like a fan so they would take it to places where weapons were not allowed. Thanks again!